# Ruby - calculations with gets.chomp in a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

I'm very new to Ruby. I've been trying to find a way to do calculations with user inputs. There are two things that I wanted to do:

1. Output which friend has the most dinosaurs or jellyfish.
2. Output which friend has the most dinosaurs and jellyfish combined.

I only have this loop requesting for user inputs so far:

```
f = "yes"

while f == "yes"
print "Enter your name: "
n = gets.chomp.to_f
print "Enter the number of dinosaurs you have: "
d = gets.chomp.to_f
print "Enter the number of jellyfish you have: "
j = gets.chomp.to_f
print "Another friend? (yes/no)"
f = gets.chomp
end
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you so much!

UPDATES:
Thank you so much for you all's help. I've realized that I was not specific enough. I'll try to clarify that here.

The output that I want looks something like this (things in ~ ~ are user inputs):

```
Enter your name: ~ Bob~
Enter the number of dinosaur you have: ~3~
Enter the number of jellyfish you have: ~6~
Another friend? (yes/no) ~yes~
Enter your name: ~ Sally~
Enter the number of dinosaur you have: ~2~
Enter the number of jellyfish you have: ~8~
Another friend? (yes/no) ~no~
Friend who has the most dinosaurs: Bob
Friend who has the most jellyfish: Sally
Friend who has the most dinosaurs and jellyfish combined: Sally
```

So far, the codes that I wrote only gets me to "Another friend? (yes/no)" but I'm not sure how to ask Ruby to output the last three lines that I want. Can you folks shed some light on this, please?

Thank you very much!

MORE UPDATES:
Thanks for all of your help! Got it figured out with Hash and Array. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You may want to review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  In particular, it seems that you may have multiple questions that you could search for pre-existing answers.  How to loop in Ruby.  How to store data in Ruby.  How to retrieve data in Ruby.  You may want to edit this question to be more specific.

Comment: "Any help is appreciated." – Help with what? You didn't state a problem! It's not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases?

Comment: Thank you so much. I have edited my question. I hope that clarifies some of the confusion. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is three-fold.

#### Collecting user input

[`gets`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) returns a line from stdin, including the newline. If the user enters <kbd>B</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd> then `gets` returns `"Bob\n"`.

To strip the newline you use [`String#chomp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/String.html#method-i-chomp):

```
"Bob\n".chomp #=> "Bob"
```

To convert an input like `"3\n"` to an integer `3`, you can use [`String#to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/String.html#method-i-to_i):

```
"3\n".to_i #=> 3
```

Note that `to_i` ignores extraneous characters (including newline), so you can avoid `chomp`.

#### Storing data

You probably want to store a user's data in one place. In an object-oriented programming language like Ruby, such "place" is often a class. It can be as simple as:

```
class User
  attr_accessor :name, :dinosaurs, :jellyfish
end
```

[`attr_accessor`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor) creates getters and setters, so you can read and write a user's attributes via:

```
user = User.new
user.name = 'Bob'
user.name #=> "Bob"
```

Since you don't want just one user, you need another place to store the users.

An [`Array`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Array.html) would work just fine:

```
users = []

user = User.new
user.name = 'Bob'
user.dinosaurs = 3

users << user

users
#=> [#<User @name="Bob", @dinosaurs=3>]
```

Adding a second user:

```
user = User.new     # <- same variable name, but new object
user.name = 'Sally'
user.dinosaurs = 2

users << user

users
#=> [#<User @name="Bob", @dinosaurs=3>, #<User @name="Sally", @dinosaurs=2>]
```

Retrieving the users (or their attributes) from the array:

```
users[0]      #=> #<User @name="Bob">
users[0].name #=> "Bob"
users[1].name #=> "Sally"
```

#### Calculating with data

`Array` includes many useful methods from the [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html) mixin.

To get an element with a maximum value there's [`max_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) – it passes each element (i.e. user) to a block and the block has to return the value you are interested in (e.g. `dinosaurs`). `max_by` then returns the user with the highest `dinosaurs` value:

```
users.max_by { |u| u.dinosaurs }
#=> #<User @name="Bob">
```

You can also *calculate* the value:

```
users.max_by { |u| u.dinosaurs + u.jellyfish }
```

But that would currently result in an exception, because we did not set `jellyfish` above.

Comment: Thank you very much! It really makes sense to populate arrays for the output! Thank you!

Comment: @lozageg you're welcome. Feel free to accept one of our answers and / or upvote them (now or later)

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're trying to turn the name into a float (number) by calling `to_f` on it. It's already a string when it's coming in from the user, and should probably stay a string.

Also, you're currently overwriting each of your variables in every iteration of your loop. So if Bob fills this out, and wants to add a friend, Sally, all of Bob's information is overwritten by Sally's.

Instead, you'll need to create a Hash or Array, then add each user to it one by one from your loop.

```
continue = "yes"
users = {}

while continue == "yes"
print "Enter your name: "
name = gets.chomp.to_f
print "Enter the number of dinosaurs you have: "
dinosaursCount = gets.chomp.to_f
print "Enter the number of jellyfish you have: "
jellyfishCount = gets.chomp.to_f

users[name] = {dinosaurs: dinosaursCount, jellyfish: jellyfishCount}

print "Another friend? (yes/no)"
continue = gets.chomp
end
```

Now if Bob and Sally have both been added through the command line, you can get their data by doing:

```
users.Bob #{dinosaurs: 10, jellyfish: 10}
users.Bob.dinosaurs #10
users.Bob.jellyfish #10
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer! I've learned something new from your answer. However, I've realized that my question was not specific enough, so I edited my question in order to clarify some confusion. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Those `to_f` calls need to be fixed, the OP apparently wants a string and two integers. Besides, you have to use `hash[key]` to access the hash's value associated with a specific key, there's no `hash.key` shortcut (at least not built-in). And you should use `snake_case` for variable names and properly indent your code.